# R language function representation

Tags: r, function

I am very new on R progrraming language, I try to write function as a below

[image: formula]

I tried to write code same as matlab but I think it is wrong.

[image: matlab representation]

How I should  write this function in R language ?
I also need plot of the function between range 0 and 600.
I would be glad if you can help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: You should show us your code, and we could tell you what is wrong with it.  You could include the Matlab code in your question as text and it would be easier for others to read.

Comment: Actually I dont need to code, I need representation of the function and plot as a graph. I showed my matlab code in 2nd image.

Comment: "How I should write this function in R language?" and " I dont need to code" are mutually contradictory. You need to be clear about your problem before asking for help in solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, you just want to define a `function(x)` which would return `y` as defined in your above formula? Then use something like

```r
## Define your function:
f <- function(x, w0 = 2.5, E = 50000, I = 30000, L = 600) {
    return(w0 / (120*E*I*L) * (-x^5 + 2 * L^2 * x^3 - L^4 * x))
}
## Plot for x from 0 to 600:
x <- 0:600
plot(f(x) ~ x, type = "l")
```

Note that you may use your constant values `w0, E, I, L` as parameters in your function (useful in case they would not be *really* constant :-)), and that you can give them default values.

Comment: Thank you sir. How I plot this function between x=0 and x=600?

Comment: I've edited my answer for this other question.